# Disabling "save" button until at least one input field has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are around 20 input fields and a save and a register buttons in a page. How can I enable a "save" button only when something changed in at least one field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Angularjs form validation:

I suppose you created a form with text inputs.

You can conditionally disable your save button (If the form is prisitine, disable the button):

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine" />
```

Working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MI3esDkbI0vtNwsPibnX?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<input>
<input>
<input>
<button class=save disabled>Save</button>
```

You can do something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var enableSave = function() {
  document.querySelector("button.save").disabled = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].removeEventListener("input", enableSave);
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("input", enableSave);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to compare values you can just attach an event handler on key event to all text boxes and enable the save button once the event in any of them is triggered.

If you need to more "sophisticated" feature to allow saving only when some data has really changed (*you may for example change "aaa" to "aa" - but then realize you want it back to "aaa"*) then you need to maintain the original data and compare them against any new changes and then determine whether you enable save button or keep it disabled. In such case you can for example add some sort of `"original-data"` attribute to your input textboxes which will hold the original value when the page is generated/loaded and on every key change event run the comparer.

Comment: complicated, but it would work. Simpler solution would be Himmet Asvar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a button for a form can be done using ng-disabled

```
<form name="myForm">
Name : 
<input type="text" name="Name" required><br>
Age:
<input type="number" name="Age" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="myForm.$error.required">
```

here the save button is enabled only when the required fields in the form is satisfied